# Fitting comparison plot_Algorithm for several dependent variables in R

Tags: regression

I have several dependent variables in my dataset and I want to find the best fit between x and each y. How can I modify the following code (loop function) to have the plot of x and all ys at the same time. Instead of running the code for each dependent variable separately, I want to run a code and have three plots for (x,y) (x,y1) and (x,y2)

```
fit1 <- read.table(header=TRUE,text="
x    y   y1 y2
1 0 2.36 3  5
2 1 1.10 3  6
3 2 0.81 4  7
4 3 0.69 1.3  8
5 4 0.64 2.3  9
6 5 0.61 4.3  15")
Various fits:

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(fit1,aes(x,y))+geom_point()+
    geom_smooth(method="glm",se=FALSE,
                method.args=list(family=gaussian(link="log")))+
    geom_smooth(method="nls",se=FALSE,
                formula=y~a+b*exp(-c*x),
                method.args=list(start=list(a=0.6,b=1.5,c=1)),
                colour="red")+
    geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE,
                formula=y~exp(-x),
                colour="purple")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use facet_grid after you melt your data

```
fit1_melt <- melt(fit1, id = "x")
ggplot(fit1_melt, aes(x=x,y=value)) + 
geom_point() + 
facet_grid(~variable)
```